How to create an entry with an immutable text part in .NET MAUI?
I'm developing a mobile app using .NET MAUI and I want to create an entry where part of the text is immutable (unchangeable). For instance, I want the entry to display "example.jpg" and when the user tries to edit it, they should only be able to modify the editable part, like changing "example.jpg" to "example2.jpg". However, they should not be able to edit the ".jpg" part, only the "example" part.
How can I achieve this in .NET MAUI? Could someone provide an example or guidance on how to implement this functionality?

You can achieve this by creating a "custom control" with a contentView. For example, a grid with 2 columns where in the first column you put an entry and in the second a label with fixed text.

are you expecting other scenarios for the immutable part or that part will always be at the end of the string like your example ?

You could use TextChanged listener and add logic to always change text to expected results. Although some scenarios could be hard to script, like text paste.

You can refer to my old answer.
